# C programming generate 2 and 4 with a percentage

Tags: c, random

```
int random;
random=rand();

        if(random<90)
        var[x][y]=2;
        else 
        var[x][y]=4;
```

How can I generate 2 at a percentage of 90% and 4 at 10 %?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more detail than this.  What is var?  What is x and y?  This question makes no sense currently.

Comment: @rost0031 I think OP wants random to get a value `<90` for 90% of the time

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `if ((random%100)<90)`?

Comment: lol I think it;s obvious that I want to ask how to generate 2 for 90 % of all time and 4 for 10 % of all time

Comment: @JiaHong sorry, but is there anything said or done that is `lol`-worthy? What is _evident_ to you, may not be clear to someone else. Just saying' :-)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: That  would not give a 90:10 split.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic idea is right, but you got the values wrong. `rand()` yields a non-negative pseudo-random number smaller then `RAND_MAX`, which is a high number and guaranteed to be at least 65535.

You can get a random floating-point number between 0 and 1 with:

```
rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)
```

If that is below 90% or 0.9, you want 2, otherwise 4. So:

```
var[x][y] = (rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0) < 0.9) ? 2 : 4;
```